# IPA string is not properly voiced on iOS

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

I'm trying to use `AVSpeechSynthesizer` with `AVSpeechSynthesisIPANotationAttribute` but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Here is the IPA notation for the pronunciation of the word "participation" taken from Wiktionary: pɑɹˌtɪsɪˈpeɪʃən. But `AVSpeechSynthesizer` does not read it correctly.

When I add a custom pronunciation using Settings -> Accessibility -> Spoken Content -> Pronunciations on my iPhone, it gives me this notation: pəɻ.ˈtɪ.sɪ.ˈpe͡ɪ.ʃən, which the iPhone reads correctly.

**Why does "pəɻ.ˈtɪ.sɪ.ˈpe͡ɪ.ʃən" work but a string like "pɑɹˌtɪsɪˈpeɪʃən" that is taken from a dictionary does not?**

Here is a sample code you can try:

```swift
import UIKit
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let pronunciationKey = NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: AVSpeechSynthesisIPANotationAttribute)
        
        let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "foo",
                                                attributes: [pronunciationKey: "pɑɹˌtɪsɪˈpeɪʃən"])
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(attributedString: attrStr)
        
        synthesizer.speak(utterance)
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help to include a reproducible code example to rule out the possibility that you're not using AVSpeechSynthesisIPANotationAttribute correctly.  https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/82861  ... You can also google "AVSpeechSynthesisIPANotationAttribute example" for more clues.

Comment: Just curious: why do you need to force the pronunciation at all -- why can't you just say speak("participation") ... is it not pronouncing that correctly?  If not, that is very strange since the engine already knows the correct pronunciation.

Comment: @NerdyBunz I added the code I was using. I'm working on a dictionary app that's why I need a speech engine that can work with IPA notation (at least for US English sounds).